# Magento SOAP-ERROR Parsing WSDL Unexpected WSDL element Action

Tags: magento, soap

I have a magento store 1.7.0.1. 
Admin is configured and verified for both WsI compliance and without.
UNSECURE URL is like **site.com/store**.

when trying to access `site.com/store/api/v2_soap/index/`
I get the following -

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><SOAP-ENV:Fault><faultcode>WSDL</faultcode><faultstring>SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Unexpected WSDL element &lt;operation&gt;</faultstring>
</SOAP-ENV:Fault></SOAP-ENV:Body></SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

I googled for what could be the cause of error, but at my wit's end. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Since I cannot add a comment as I am 7 points shy of being allowed to comment, I would need more clarifications before I can try to find out whats wrong here. It looks more like when echoing the xml string `<operation>` its getting escaped as `&lt;operation&gt;`.

Have you installed any modules which might affect SOAP response? Which server are you using?Which PHP version? All these details will help identifying the problem. I will edit this answer if I am able to identify it correctly

Answer (score 0):

I found an extra '>' in my wsdl file. It caused an 'Unexpected WSDL element ' error.